# Knockout binding with placeholders inside script tag

Tags: javascript, magento, knockout.js

In Magento I have a template presenting JSON data from a block like so:

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "MyModule/js/chat" : {
                "customerId" : <?= $block->getCustomerId() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

The customer ID is picked up by some JS loaded later.

What I'm trying to do is use Magento's customer-data library, and Knockout, to refresh the data in the UI so that the page can still be cached.

All the examples show how to use a `data-bind` attribute to bind data to an HTML element - but is it possible to have a placeholder inside a script tag like e.g.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init" data-bind="scope: 'chatData'" data-role="chat-data-provider">
    {
        "*": {
            "MyModule/js/chat" : {
                "customerId" : chatData().customerId
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Potentially I need to do everything in the JS loaded later, and not use this JSON snippet.